# Zanussi dryer switches off near the end of a cycle

Tags: dryer, appliances

I have a Zanussi ZTE171 clothes dryer which lately is turning off before the cycle is complete, the dials go dead at some point (clothes are almost dry, but not quite).
Seems like overheating because after a few minutes if I turn the dial I can start it again.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Imagine you clean out lint filter.   Possible the heat sensor is weak/off or there is a problem.  Have you checked the exhaust vent for blockage?

Comment: It would be normal for it to turn off when the humidity sensor reports.

Comment: @crip659 filters are all cleaned after a cycle and the ventilation exhaust is in front side of the machine, so it's always clear. 
thanks

Comment: @Ruskes the behavior is not normal because when a cycle finishes it stops but there are LED indications of some kind. With the current issue, all LED lights and information turn off which never happened before.  Thanks